# Sorting half empty array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hello I want to sort my array of strings

```
String[] listaU = new String[3];
```

using

```
Arrays.sort(listaU);
```

It works well when I make this array full, but when I add for example only 2 strings it doesn't work. Is there any way to sort not "finished" array?

Comment: which sorting result will you expect?

Comment: Have you considered initializing the array to values that will be sorted to the very end (or begining)?

Comment: With java-8, you could do `Arrays.sort(listaU, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));` or `nullsLast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Arrays.sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)` method.

Comment: What if OP set only first and last element?

Comment: Then OP should have written a better question :-).

Comment: question does not says elements are correlative, so you must better reading

Comment: "Then OP should have written a better question :-)" question is OK, if you need farther informations from OP ask about them in comment.

Comment: I don't understand.  By default, if you leave you leave nulls in the array, then `Arrays.sort(Object[])` fails with NullPointerException.  You can use the fromIndex/toIndex to limit the sorting to a subset of the array that contains non-null values.

Comment: It worked, thank you. And sorry for not being specific enough, elements were supposed to be added in order.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort` can be used only on array of elements which are `Comparable` (contain `compareTo`) method.

Also arrays of objects (like Strings) are filled with `null`s and you can't invoke

```
null.compareTo("foo");
```

because `null` doesn't have any type, which also means no methods. It will simply throw `NullPointerException` when we try to execute such code.

What you need to do is use `Arrays.sort(array, comparator)` where your comparator will handle cases where it will be comparing `null`s.

Lets say that we want to move all `null`s at the end of array. Lets also assume case insensitive order of elements. In that case your code could look like

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null)   return 0;// no swap needed
        if (o1 == null)                 return 1;// null is bigger, swap left with right
        if (o2 == null)                 return -1;// null is smaller
        return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(o1, o2);
    }

});
```

---

Since Java 8 above code can simplified to

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.nullsLast(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own comparator that handles `null` as desired, for example:

```
String[] listaU = new String[3];

// add elements you need

Arrays.sort(listaU, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return 0;
        if (s1 == null) return 1;
        if (s2 == null) return -1;
        return s1.compare(s2);
    }
});
```